# Filter rows only if columns list contains values from another list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe, where one column is a list:

```
import pandas as pd 

data = [{'colA': 'ID1', 'colB': ['A', 'B', 'C']}, 
        {'colA': 'ID2', 'colB': ['A']}, 
        {'colA': 'ID3', 'colB': ['B']}, 
        {'colA': 'ID4', 'colB': ['A', 'B']},
        {'colA': 'ID5', 'colB': ['C', 'D']}] 

df = pd.DataFrame(data) 
df 

    colA    colB
0   ID1     [A, B, C]
1   ID2     [A]
2   ID3     [B]
3   ID4     [A, B]
4   ID5     [C, D]
```

I want to filter rows so that only those rows that contain only values from another list are selected. However, any row that contains any value not present in another list should not be selected.

```
valid_list = ['A', 'B']
```

Expected result

```
   colA colB
0   ID1 [A, B, C] #not selected because it contains C
1   ID2 [A] #Valid
2   ID3 [B] #Valid
3   ID4 [A, B] #Valid
4   ID5 [C, D] #Not valid - Either values not present in valid list
```

final dataframe:

```
   colA colB
0   ID2 [A] 
1   ID3 [B] 
2   ID4 [A, B]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `np.isin` and `all`

```
df[df.colB.map(lambda x: np.isin(x, valid_list).all())]

Out[217]:
  colA    colB
1  ID2  [A]
2  ID3  [B]
3  ID4  [A, B]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `issubset` with `set`s:

```
df = df[df.colB.map(lambda x: set(x).issubset(valid_list))]
```

---

```
df = df[df.colB.map(lambda x: set(x) <= set(valid_list))]
```

---

```
print (df)
  colA    colB
1  ID2     [A]
2  ID3     [B]
3  ID4  [A, B]
```

Answer (score 1):

using [np.setdiff1d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html)

```
df[df.colB.apply(lambda x: False if len(np.setdiff1d(x,valid_list)) >= 1 else True)]
```

OR

```
df[~df.colB.apply(lambda x: len(np.setdiff1d(x,valid_list)) >= 1)]
```

---

```
 colA    colB
1  ID2     [A]
2  ID3     [B]
3  ID4  [A, B]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also apply a function to get the mask:

```
df = df[df.colB.apply(lambda lst: all(x in valid_list for x in lst))]
```

---

```
print(df)
  colA    colB
1  ID2     [A]
2  ID3     [B]
3  ID4  [A, B]
```